# Model stuck on base

Tags: 3d-models

I've printed the same model at least twice and both times it was impossible to separate from the base material it was printed on.

I'm using a QIDITECH dual extruder, when I start the print it uses the right side extruder to print a base layer, which is not part of the original model, it seems MakerBot issues this instruction to the printer.

Once the initial layer has been printed it then prints the model.

Both extruders are loaded with PETG.  In the left side I am printed with a transparent material.  The model I am trying to print is a flat rectangle 2 mm thick.

The problem is that once it has completed printing I'm finding it impossible to separate from the initial layer it put down.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "base" you are referring to is normally called a "raft". It's not very common to print with a raft these days (it was originally used to help with bed adhesion, but the current-day standard is to use a heated bed if available in combination with some surface preparation (hair spray, PEI sheets, etc...) to aid adhesion); you might consider just disabling the raft.

Alternatively, you could consider (since you have a dual extruder) to print the raft in a different material that is more easily removed from the main material. There exist materials that are specifically formulated to break away easily from your print, and another option is to use a (water-)soluble material for the raft and any supports.

Comment: Makerbot really like rafts, probably because they minimize bad calibration effects. I also really like rafts, because my time is worth more to me than a few extra ¢ of plastic. But it also sounds like his raft settings are hosed up ("single layer" and "impossible to separate" are not normal characteristics of a Makerbot raft).

Comment: I'm so new to 3d printing, I haven't played with the settings in maker bot, its all printing using the defaults.  two more prints binned today.